# NPM proxy problem when trying to install Vue CLI globally

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-install

I've tried to install **Vue Cli** globally, but doesn't install and also shows me some errors which is proxy settings. I've manually/cmd added some values on **.npmrc** file like below but it does not works for me.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
```

The errors are below:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Viking_Castle\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-10T15_30_01_181Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing proxies with the following command the try to install it

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219583/discussion-on-answer-by-avinash-chandravansi-how-i-can-resolve-this-npm-proxy-pr).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error

```
  Initializing git repository...
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network request to https://cdn.npm.taobao.org/%40babel/plugin-transform-unicode-escapes/-/%40babel/plugin-transform-unicode-escapes-7.12.1.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 129.227.206.207:443 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pradeep S\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-27T19_57_22_034Z-debug.log  ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

R**esolved by changing Wifi connection to laptop**. Used mobile hotspot to connect and tried creating project from vue cli again, and it worked this time